# A method of writing all primes

Tags: linear-algebra, prime-numbers

I've recently noticed a method of describing primes. As an example: $13=5*11-2*3*7$. This pattern must follow these rules: $x-y$ such that $x*y$ is the product of all previous primes (allowing powers of those primes as well) where $x$ and $y$ are relatively prime positive integers, and $1<x-y<z^2$ where $z$ is the largest prime factor of $x$ or $y$. If these hold true, it's guaranteed to be prime.

I've also noticed that this pattern can yield the very next prime in cases up to 29 (i.e. $5=3^2-2^2$, $7=3*5-2^3$, $11=7*5-2^3*3$, $13=5*11-2*3*7$, $17=2*7*13-3*5*11$ etc.

My question is, can $29$ be achieved in this manner though use of its previous primes $(2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23)$, and is there a way to prove that each "next prime" may be found in this manner?

Comment: How do you find the exponents in the powers? How do you prove that the result is guaranteed to be prime?

Comment: It may be worth noting that there can be multiple expressions, e.g., $5=3^2-2^2=2^5-3^3$ and $7=3\cdot5-2^3=5^2-2\cdot3^2$.

Comment: This can be explored programmatically to a great extent, but the combinatorics blow up very early on. Guess it doesn't bother you that $2,3$ don't fit, either.

Comment: Sorry, post was already getting long so I left out some details. As to your 2nd question, Pin, in example $13=5*11-2*3*7$, as 2*3*7 must be divisible by 2 (2 is a factor) and 5*11 cannot be divisible by 2 (only prime factors are 5 and 11) subtracting the two must yield something also not divisible by 2. As long as a number $n$ is a factor of exactly one of the terms being subtracted, the difference CANNOT be divisible by $n$. Also, since checking for primes only requires you to check up to the square root of a number, as long as 13 is less than 11^2, the only primes we need to check are 2-11.

Comment: Very true Barry! Another interesting thought would be: "Are there infinitely many ways of achieving 5 or 7?" Perhaps finding one implies infinite? Maybe I'll post that as another question...

Comment: Rschwieb, yeah, using 1 to achieve those is cheating I guess as in $2^2-1=3$. 2 and 3 are interesting primes. I think one of the guys on Numberphile debates whether 2 or 3 should even be considered prime. Figure we'll tackle those bigger than 3 first then debate 2 and 3 later.

Comment: As to your first question, Pin, I agree that the exponents make it difficult. without exponents, you could use $x-y=13$ and $xy=2*3*5*7*11$ as a system of equations. I've found through brute force though that using just an exponent of 1 doesn't work with some. Not sure how to setup a system of equations with variable exponents.

Comment: On thinking a bit about the stated "rules" for your pattern, you haven't ruled out things like $2\cdot3-5$, $3\cdot5-2\cdot7$, etc.  I.e., you need to include the rule that $x-y\gt1$ in order to guarantee what you get is a prime.

Comment: Thanks Barry, edited the question to reflect that.